# Is it possible to detect pressed key after specific key combination pressed?

Tags: javascript

We are using a text editor which causes problem with its default events. So far I managed to detect `Ctrl + C - Ctrl + V` events etc.

However, what i'm trying to do is catching "Backspace" key **after** **Ctrl A** pressed but user will press Ctrl and A keys and then release them, and then user will press Backspace key.

So basically I'm trying to catch that user first pressed Ctrl + A and selects whole text in editor and then stops pressing, after that he presses Backspace key.

Comment: what code have you tried? I suspect you'd want to be keeping a buffer of keypresses to record the sequence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a variable that stores if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is pressed, then check if backspace is pressed.

In this code snippet I am using a sample `<textarea>`.

```js
const textbox = document.getElementById('textbox'); // get the element and store it to a variable
let ctrlA = false;

textbox.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'a') {
    ctrlA = true;
  } else if (e.key === 'Backspace' && ctrlA) {
    alert('Backspace pressed after Ctrl + A!'); // do something else here
    ctrlA = false;
  } else {
    ctrlA = false;
   }
})
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
```

[`event.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) checks if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is being held and [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) checks if <kbd>A</kbd> is pressed. If the above is true, it sets the variable `ctrlA` to true. In the same [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), we check if `ctrlA` is true and use `event.key` again to check if the backspace key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a sequence of keypresses, you can use a buffer to store recently pressed keys - then check that against your desired sequence... something like this...

```js
var buffer = [];
var bufferTimer;

function listen(evt) {
  // encode the keypress in a simple format
  var keyCombo = evt.keyCode;
  // detect ctrl key, or mac equivelent
  if (evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey) {
    keyCombo += '+';
  }
  // store it in the buffer
  buffer.push(keyCombo);
  // check the last 2 buffer elements
  // to see if they match Ctrl+A then B
  if (buffer.slice(-2).join() === "65+,66") {
    console.log("ctrl+a, then b pressed!");
  };
  // clear the buffer array after a full second
  if (bufferTimer) clearTimeout(bufferTimer);
  bufferTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    buffer = [];
  }, 5000);
}
// listen for all keypresses everywhere
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', listen);
```